# Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory. Eventhough they are in same directory

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tokenize, text-processing

I am trying different text processing model. I am trying to use spacy and it's model en_core_web_lg.

```
import spacy
import spacy.language
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector
from spacy.language import Language



@Language.factory('language_detector')
def language_detector(nlp, name):
    return LanguageDetector()
```

```
my_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
my_nlp.add_pipe('language_detector')
```

But while running this i am getting following error:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-4cd126296f60> in <module>
----> 1 my_nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
      2 my_nlp.add_pipe('language_detector')


~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     49     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     50     """
---> 51     return util.load_model(
     52         name,
     53         vocab=vocab,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    470     if name in OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS:
    471         raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name]))  # type: ignore[index]
--> 472     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    473 
    474 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I manually checked the directory of both spacy and en_core_web_lg, they both are present inside the site-packages.

I even tried to create a new virtual environment and install and run the code but getting same error.

I tried the solutions given by ChatGPT like manually inserting the
`[paths] en_core_web_lg = /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/en_core_web_lg`
inside the confid.cfg folder in spacy and `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH` environment variable but getting the same error. It's possible that there might be an environment-specific or platform-specific factor causing this problem? If not please help me solve this error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before making any changes, please open your terminal and type:

```
python -m spacy info
```

This command will display a list of installed models. Look for the model named 'en_core_web_lg'. If it's installed, double-check if you've typed it correctly. If it's not working, you can try uninstalling it using the following command:

```
python -m spacy uninstall en_core_web_lg
```

You can always install the model by opening your terminal and typing:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

This will ensure that the model is installed correctly. Once done, remember to restart your runtime environment. If you prefer to give it an absolute path, go ahead with:

```
nlp = spacy.load('/path/to/en_core_web_lg')
```

If none of the above solutions work for you, I recommend visiting [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage) to explore other available models based on their efficiency or accuracy.